# Kali Linux explain output

Tags: kali-linux

[image] What are the errors if any from this screen shot?

The output I received was confusing to me. I have the screen shot for reference.

4. At the command prompt, type cd ~/stonesoup-c-mc/TC_C_121_v968/src and press Enter to change the directory.
5. At the command prompt, type vi random_lw.c and press Enter to review the program in the editor.
6. In the Lab Report file, document any errors, bugs, or security flaws you find.

Comment: How does the screenshot relate to the stonesoup output?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a command line. this is a VIM text editor, and you have opened a C language program in it. you can press ":wq" to exit this editor and you will be back on the command line